# adding the product to cart table in different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a shopping cart.

This is the code where a user clicks on a dd to cart button to add items to the cart table:

```
    <div class="container">
<a class="addToCart" href="#" data-name="Java" data-price="150"><a/>
<img src="1.jpeg" id="book1" width="200" height="175" />
    <div class="center">Java Basics</div>
    <p> 150 SAR </p>
            <div>
                <label for="qty-1">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="1" size="5"/>
            </div>
            <p><input id="addToCart" type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn"/></p>
</div>

<div class="container1">
<a class="addToCart" href="#" data-name="PHP" data-price="100"><a/>
<img src="1.jpeg" id="book1" width="200" height="175" />
    <div class="center">PHP Basics</div>
    <p> 100 SAR </p>
            <div>
                <label for="qty-1">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="1" size="5"/>
            </div>
            <p><input id="addToCart" type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn"/></p>
</div>

<div class="container2">
<a class="addToCart" href="#" data-name="PHP" data-price="100"><a/>
<img src="1.jpeg" id="book1" width="200" height="175" />
    <div class="center">JavaScript Basics</div>
    <p> 200 SAR </p>
            <div>
                <label for="qty-1">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" name="qty-1" id="qty-1" class="qty" value="1" size="5"/>
            </div>
            <p><input id="addToCart" type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn"/></p>
</div>
```

with this jQuery script: 
and I have javascript file that contains function of the cart like add to cart, remove from car and calculating total.

```
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script>

// some jQuery function added to the links

$("#totalCart").html();

$(".addToCart")click(function(event){
eventpreventDefault(); //prevent the links from doing the default behaviour when they are clicked 
var name= $(this).att("data-name"); //this represents the link that you click on / attr to access one of the attributes
var price= Number($(this).att("data-price"));

addItemtoCart(name, price, 1); 
displayCart();
});

function displayCart() {  //display cart content into the page as a list 
var cartArray = listCart();
var output = "" ; 
for ( var i in cartArray) { 
output += "<li>" +cartArray[i].name+"  "+cartArray[i].quantity+"</li>"
}
$("#showCart").html(output);  //html(output) to replace everything in showCart with text we want
$("#totalCart").html(total Cart());
}
```

and this the cart.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<form id="shopping-cart" action="cart.html" method="post">

<table style="width:80%">
  <tr>
    <th> Item </th>
    <th> Quantity </th> 
    <th> Price </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

my question is that I want to link add to cart button to the cart.html page with implementing the functions, I do not know how to glue them all together. Using only HtML, JavaScript and a little bit of jQuery.

PS: no database is used.

Comment: When the user click on add to cart, the item should get reflected in the cart.html  isn't it ? Is it your requirement ?

Comment: yes that is it.

Comment: Why have you put the table inside <form> in the cart.html page ? If the page is intended to display cart items you don't have to put it inside the form.

Comment: I deleted the form element already.

Comment: Usually, `database` should be involved in these kind of operations. Once you hit on `add to cart` button, using AJAX or something the data must be stored in the database as a record. And when you open the `cart` page, the saved records should be displayed.

Comment: It is a small assignment that I do not have to use databases.

Comment: Hmmm.. It's how it's done usually. Anyway, you can use web storage then.